# Embedding PDF data from Java Sevlet

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, embed

I have a database with PDF data in it. I've successfully called that data and wrote it to a PDF file on my hard drive using Java. Now, I need to send that data to a web client for it to embed inside an HTML. I've found a lot of different posts on this topic, dozens in fact, but they all have subtle variations (different coding language, trying to open the pdf in a new window, different data types) on this theme that has me still perplexed.

Here is my Java Code:

```
package fullView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "GetDocuments", urlPatterns = {"/GetDocuments"})
public class GetDocuments extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement prst = null;

    String connUrl = "Connection data omitted";


    String sql = "select * from Table where type LIKE 'application/pdf%' and id = '5'";


    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl);
        prst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = prst.executeQuery();
        File[] files;
        while(rs.next()){
            byte[] arr = rs.getBytes("data");
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(arr.length));
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"something.pdf\"");
            response.getOutputStream().write(arr);
            response.getOutputStream().close();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        String error = e.toString();
        error = "The Error is: " + error;
        error = " " + error;

    }

}


public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

There is a div called "docHolder" that I want to embed the pdf into. This is the latest among the dozens of ways I've tried to make this worL

```
function embedFile(){
            $.get("GetDocuments?ER=ER1471378280115", function(responseText){                    
                 responseText = b64EncodeUnicode(responseText);  
                 var String = "<object data='data:application/pdf;base64," + responseText + "' type='application/pdf' width='700px%' height='100%'></object>";                     
                 $("#docHolder").append(String);
            });
        }
```

What I get back in "responseText" is the "%PDF1.4" type of string. This code does render a PDF, but it is numerous blank pages. I confirmed the data contains more than just blank pages via the "Write to disk" method.

Comment: Have you tried PDF.js? https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: I took a look at it briefly with the intention of looking further, but my initial impression was that it created a webpage that was entirely a PDF, rather than an embedded one. I'll take a longer look, see if I can use it to embed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your content-type on the server as application/pdf.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
```

instead of

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "Your staffs content type");
```

I don't know what framework you use in javascript but, it is possible that they use the content-type in the http headers to determine the document type.

I created a simple test case to help you

```
@Test
public void test_servlet() throws ServletException, IOException,  URISyntaxException{

    GetDocuments servlet = new GetDocuments();
    HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

    ServletOutputStream os = new ServletOutputStream() {

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Inside my stream");
            Files.write(Paths.get("MyFile.pdf"), b, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);

        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setWriteListener(WriteListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return true;
        }
    };


    Mockito.when(response.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(os);


    servlet.doGet(request, response);

}
```

Running this, your data will be written inside MyFile.pdf, if the MyFile.pdf looks also blank with pages, that means it is a data problem.

Here are the dependencies that I used

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Let's see if that helps.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't fix anything. I did add an update at the end. I have been getting a PDF back that is just multiple blank pages. The number of pages is accurate, but there is no content.

Comment: Are you sure your query return the correct data?  If you execute the code outside servlet and write to a file, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work. That's how I know I'm getting the correct number of pages.